# Python: How do I get a list of permutations of subsets?

Tags: python, permutation, combinations

Let's say I have the following list:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to get the following output:

```
[[1], [2],[3]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
[[2], [1, 3]]
[[3], [1, 2]]
```

Except I'm not even sure if I phrased the question correctly. It's basically like non-repeating groups of permutations?

Comment: I believe that what he wants to do is to get all permutations in cycle notation.

Comment: Are you looking for something like powerset? http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: I think I can write a program to generate your exact output, but I don't get how you get your output... Can you explain it more?

Answer (score -1):

It's not particularly clear to me how you came to your output (another example or a better description may help), but the answer probably lies in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), which contains a number of tools to work with combinations and permutations:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(zip(reversed(data), itertools.combinations(data, 2)))
[(3, (1, 2)), (2, (1, 3)), (1, (2, 3))]
```

Comment: It would be useful to get a reason with the down-vote - while I agree this might not be the perfect answer, given the ambiguity of the question, it's the best possible. It's definitely not 'not useful'.